# What is the best workaround for the WCF client `using` block issue?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, using, wcf-client

I like instantiating my WCF service clients within a `using` block as it's pretty much the standard way to use resources that implement `IDisposable`:

```
using (var client = new SomeWCFServiceClient()) 
{
    //Do something with the client 
}
```

But, as noted in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx), wrapping a WCF client in a `using` block could mask any errors that result in the client being left in a faulted state (like a timeout or communication problem). Long story short, when `Dispose()` is called, the client's `Close()` method fires, but throws an error because it's in a faulted state. The original exception is then masked by the second exception. Not good.

The suggested workaround in the MSDN article is to completely avoid using a `using` block, and to instead instantiate your clients and use them something like this:

```
try
{
    ...
    client.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
    throw;
}
```

Compared to the `using` block, I think that's ugly. And a lot of code to write each time you need a client.

Luckily, I found a few other workarounds, such as this one on the (now defunct) IServiceOriented blog. You start with:

```
public delegate void UseServiceDelegate<T>(T proxy); 

public static class Service<T> 
{ 
    public static ChannelFactory<T> _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(""); 
    
    public static void Use(UseServiceDelegate<T> codeBlock) 
    { 
        IClientChannel proxy = (IClientChannel)_channelFactory.CreateChannel(); 
        bool success = false; 
        try 
        { 
            codeBlock((T)proxy); 
            proxy.Close(); 
            success = true; 
        } 
        finally 
        { 
            if (!success) 
            { 
                proxy.Abort(); 
            } 
        } 
     } 
}
```

Which then allows:

```
Service<IOrderService>.Use(orderService => 
{ 
    orderService.PlaceOrder(request); 
});
```

That's not bad, but I don't think it's as expressive and easily understandable as the `using` block.

The workaround I'm currently trying to use I first read about on [blog.davidbarret.net](http://blog.davidbarrett.net/archive/2007/11.aspx). Basically, you override the client's `Dispose()` method wherever you use it. Something like:

```
public partial class SomeWCFServiceClient : IDisposable
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose() 
    {
        if (this.State == CommunicationState.Faulted) 
        {
            this.Abort();
        } 
        else 
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to be able to allow the `using` block again without the danger of masking a faulted state exception.

So, are there any other gotchas I have to look out for using these workarounds? Has anybody come up with anything better?

Comment: The last one (which inspects this.State) is a race; it might not be faulted when you check the boolean, but might be faulted when you call Close().

Comment: You read state; it's not faulted.  Before you call Close(), the channel faults.  Close() throws.  Game over.

Comment: Time passes. It may be a very short period of time, but technically, in the time period between checking the state of the channel and asking it to close, the channel's state may change.

Comment: I went with the solution found here: http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/  Good topic, unfortunate, but I'm glad it was here when I needed it...

Comment: I'd use `Action<T>` instead of `UseServiceDelegate<T>`. minor.

Comment: I really do not like this static helper `Service<T>` since it complicates unit testing (as most static things do). I would prefer it to be non-static so it can be injected into the class that is using it.

Comment: Be aware not to make large WCF contracts, otherwise the first cold start using the ChannelFactory will kill your performance on the first call. You can of course cache the factory, but for developers it is a nightmare each time to have this cold start on each start.

Comment: Just ran across this but have not investigated: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChannelAdam.Wcf

Comment: @PatrickPeters ***large WCF contracts*** _good patterns and practices_ ? 

full _source code sample_ using `Cache ChannelFactory` using **P&P** ? 

**References**: 
[how-to-call‌​-wcf-service-properl‌​y](https://devzone.channeladam.com/articles/2014/07/how-to-call-wcf-service-properly/) 
and 
[how-to-easily-call-wcf-service-properly](https://devzone.channeladam.com/articles/2014/09/how-to-easily-call-wcf-service-properly/) 
and 
https://dzimchuk.net/post/wcf-error-helpers

Comment: @jinzai **best workaround** is
[how-to-call‌​-wcf-service-properl‌​y](https://devzone.channeladam.com/articles/2014/07/how-to-call-wcf-service-properly/) . The best explanation about it and contains full source code.

Comment: @Brian Can a channel fault asynchronously if it's only used synchronously?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Actually, although I [blogged](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html) (see [Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue/573917#573917)), I think [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20100703123454/http://old.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Indisposable+-+WCF+Gotcha+1.aspx) is better than my IDisposable wrapper. Typical code:

```
Service<IOrderService>.Use(orderService=>
{
  orderService.PlaceOrder(request);
});
```

---

(edit per comments)

Since `Use` returns void, the easiest way to handle return values is via a captured variable:

```
int newOrderId = 0; // need a value for definite assignment
Service<IOrderService>.Use(orderService=>
  {
    newOrderId = orderService.PlaceOrder(request);
  });
Console.WriteLine(newOrderId); // should be updated
```

Comment: @MarcGravell Where could I inject that client? I assume that the ChannelFactory creates the client, and the factory object is newed inside the Service class, which means that the code should be refactored a bit to allow a custom factory. Is this correct, or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You could easily modify the wrapper so you don't need a capture variable for the result. Something like this:

`public static TResult Use<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> codeBlock) { ... }`

Comment: Maybe useful

 `https://devzone.channeladam.com/articles/2014/07/how-to-call-wcf-service-properly/`

and

 `https://devzone.channeladam.com/articles/2014/09/how-to-easily-call-wcf-service-properly/`

and

 `http://dzimchuk.net/post/wcf-error-helpers`

Comment: How can I add credential by using this way?

Comment: how can we improve this to utilize async/await ?

Comment: @MohammadZekrallah did you use finally ***async/await*** ?

Comment: @Hippasus did you use ***credential*** ?

Comment: In my opinion, the most correct solution would:

***1) Perform the Close/Abort pattern without a race condition
2) Handle the situation when the service operation throws exceptions
3) Handle the situations when both the Close and Abort methods throw exceptions
4) Handle asynchronous exceptions such as the ThreadAbortException***

`https://devzone.channeladam.com/articles/2014/07/how-to-call-wcf-service-properly/`

Comment: it should be noted that the performance of this solution (using a delegate with a closure) will cause additional memory overhead and does not scale well under extremely high load.

Comment: `new ChannelFactory<T>(""); ` throws an exception *Could not find endpoint element with name ''*. Am I missing something?

Comment: What if you had many methods returning a variety of things. For instance: "PlaceOrder" (returning a void), "GetOrder" (returning an int) and "GetAllOrders()" (returning an int[]). How would you do that?

Comment: Caching the channel factory sounds all kinds of wrong to me, because when the channel  gets faulted, *so does the factory* (trying to dispose it also throws `CommunicationObjectFaultedException`)!

Answer (score 92):

Given a choice between the solution advocated by IServiceOriented.com and the solution advocated by [David Barret's blog](http://blog.davidbarrett.net/archive/2007/11.aspx), I prefer the simplicity offered by overriding the client's Dispose() method.  This allows me to continue to use the using() statement as one would expect with a disposable object.  However, as @Brian pointed out, this solution contains a race condition in that the State might not be faulted when it is checked but could be by the time Close() is called, in which case the CommunicationException still occurs.

So, to get around this, I've employed a solution that mixes the best of both worlds.

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    bool success = false;
    try 
    {
        if (State != CommunicationState.Faulted) 
        {
            Close();
            success = true;
        }
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (!success) 
            Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't it risky to use the 'Try-Finally' (or the syntactical sugar - "using(){}") statement with unmanaged resources?  Case in point, if the "Close" option fails, the exception is not caught, and finally may not run.  Also, if there is an exception in the finally statement it can mask other exceptions.  I think that is why Try-Catch is preferred.

Comment: Zack, not clear on your object; what am I missing?  If the Close method throws an exception, the finally block will execute before the exception is thrown up.  Right?

Comment: @jmoreno, I undid your edit.  If you'll notice, there is no catch block at all in the method.  The idea is that *any* exception that occurs (even in the finally) should be thrown, not silently caught.

Comment: @MattDavis Why do you need `success` flag at all? Why not `try { Close(); } catch { Abort(); throw; }`?

Comment: What about putting a try/catch around `Close(); success = true;`?  I wouldn't want an exception thrown if I could successfully abort it in the finally block.  I'd only want an exception thrown if the Abort() failed in that case.  This way, the try/catch would hide the potential race condition exception and still allow you to abort() the connection in the finally block.

Comment: Just to clarify, I meant to say to use a try/catch - without re-throwing.  (I'm past the 5 min edit comment window.)

Comment: I think the reason we want the exception to be thrown is that if we fail **here**, it means it hadn't failed before (since the channel wasn't faulted yet), so in this precise case an exception would not mask an existing one.

Answer (score 34):

I wrote a [higher order function](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315041245/http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2007/08/13/Practical+Functional+C+Part+II.aspx) to make it work right. We've used this in several projects and it seems to work great. This is how things should have been done from the start, without the "using" paradigm or so on.

```
TReturn UseService<TChannel, TReturn>(Func<TChannel, TReturn> code)
{
    var chanFactory = GetCachedFactory<TChannel>();
    TChannel channel = chanFactory.CreateChannel();
    bool error = true;
    try {
        TReturn result = code(channel);
        ((IClientChannel)channel).Close();
        error = false;
        return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (error) {
            ((IClientChannel)channel).Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

You can make calls like this:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int sum = UseService((ICalculator calc) => calc.Add(a, b));
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

This is pretty much just like you have in your example. In some projects, we write strongly typed helper methods, so we end up writing things like "Wcf.UseFooService(f=>f...)".

I find it quite elegant, all things considered. Is there a particular problem you encountered?

This allows other nifty features to be plugged in. For instance, on one site, the site authenticates to the service on behalf of the logged in user. (The site has no credentials by itself.) By writing our own "UseService" method helper, we can configure the channel factory the way we want, etc. We're also not bound to using the generated proxies -- any interface will do.

Comment: I'm getting exception: *The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null.  The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified*. What is `GetCachedFactory` method?

Comment: Caching the channel factory sounds all kinds of wrong to me, because when the channel  gets faulted, *so does the factory* (trying to dispose it also throws `CommunicationObjectFaultedException`)!

Answer (score 30):

This is Microsoft's recommended way to handle WCF client calls:

For more detail see: [Expected Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354510.aspx)

```
try
{
    ...
    double result = client.Add(value1, value2);
    ...
    client.Close();
}
catch (TimeoutException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", exception.GetType());
    client.Abort();
}
catch (CommunicationException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", exception.GetType());
    client.Abort();
}
```

**Additional information**
So many people seem to be asking this question on WCF that Microsoft even created a dedicated sample to demonstrate how to handle exceptions:

c:\WF_WCF_Samples\WCF\Basic\Client\ExpectedExceptions\CS\client

Download the sample:
[C#](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en) or  [VB](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vb2010samples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4174)

Considering that there are so many issues [involving the using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx), [(heated?) Internal discussions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4cdc67e0-3069-4d3b-b94f-27e2b8ff4429/) and [threads](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b95b91c7-d498-446c-b38f-ef132989c154/) on this issue, I'm not going to waste my time trying to become a code cowboy and find a cleaner way.  I'll just suck it up, and implement WCF clients this verbose (yet trusted) way for my server applications.

**Optional Additional Failures to catch**

Many exceptions derive from `CommunicationException` and I don't think most of those exceptions should be retried.  I drudged through each exception on MSDN and found a short list of retry-able exceptions (in addition to `TimeOutException` above). Do let me know if I missed an exception that should be retried.

```
  // The following is typically thrown on the client when a channel is terminated due to the server closing the connection.
catch (ChannelTerminatedException cte)
{
secureSecretService.Abort();
// todo: Implement delay (backoff) and retry
}

// The following is thrown when a remote endpoint could not be found or reached.  The endpoint may not be found or 
// reachable because the remote endpoint is down, the remote endpoint is unreachable, or because the remote network is unreachable.
catch (EndpointNotFoundException enfe)
{
secureSecretService.Abort();
// todo: Implement delay (backoff) and retry
}

// The following exception that is thrown when a server is too busy to accept a message.
catch (ServerTooBusyException stbe)
{
secureSecretService.Abort();
// todo: Implement delay (backoff) and retry
}
```

Admittedly, this is a bit of mundane code to write.  I currently prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9370880/328397), and don't see any "hacks" in that code that may cause issues down the road.

Comment: Is the code from the sample still causing issues?  I tried running the UsingUsing project (VS2013) but the line with `"Hope this code wasn't important, because it might not happen."` is still executed...

Answer (score 14):

I've finally found some solid steps towards a clean solution to this problem.

> This custom tool extends WCFProxyGenerator to provide an exception handling proxy. It generates an additional proxy called `ExceptionHandlingProxy<T>` which inherits `ExceptionHandlingProxyBase<T>` - the latter of which implements the meat of the proxy's functionality. The result is that you can choose to use the default proxy that inherits `ClientBase<T>` or `ExceptionHandlingProxy<T>` which encapsulates managing the lifetime of the channel factory and channel. ExceptionHandlingProxy respects your selections in the Add Service Reference dialog with respect to asynchronous methods and collection types.

[Codeplex](http://wcfproxygenerator.codeplex.com/) has a project called **Exception Handling WCF Proxy Generator**. It basically installs a new custom tool to Visual Studio 2008, then use this tool to generate the new service proxy *(Add service reference)*. It has some nice functionality to deal with faulted channels, timeouts and safe disposal. There's an excellent video here called [ExceptionHandlingProxyWrapper](http://wcfguidanceforwpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=28192#DownloadId=70902) explaining exactly how this works.

You can safely use the `Using` statement again, and if the channel is faulted on any request (TimeoutException or CommunicationException), the Wrapper will re-initialize the faulted channel and retry the query. If that fails then it will call the `Abort()` command and dispose of the proxy and rethrow the Exception. If the service throws a `FaultException` code it will stop executing, and the proxy will be aborted safely throwing the correct exception as expected.

Comment: @Shimmy Status Beta. ***Date: Sat Jul 11, 2009*** by ***Michele Bustamante***. Dead Project?

Answer (score 11):

Based on answers by Marc Gravell, MichaelGG, and Matt Davis, our developers came up with the following:

```
public static class UsingServiceClient
{
    public static void Do<TClient>(TClient client, Action<TClient> execute)
        where TClient : class, ICommunicationObject
    {
        try
        {
            execute(client);
        }
        finally
        {
            client.DisposeSafely();
        }
    }

    public static void DisposeSafely(this ICommunicationObject client)
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            if (client.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                client.Close();
                success = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
string result = string.Empty;

UsingServiceClient.Do(
    new MyServiceClient(),
    client =>
    result = client.GetServiceResult(parameters));
```

It's as close to the "using" syntax as possible, you don't have to return a dummy value when calling a void method, and you can make multiple calls to the service (and return multiple values) without having to use tuples.

Also, you can use this with `ClientBase<T>` descendants instead of ChannelFactory if desired.

The extension method is exposed if a developer wants to manually dispose of a proxy/channel instead.

Comment: Is using this makes sense if I'm using PoolingDuplex and do not close connection after a call so my client service might live even few days and handle server callbacks. As far as I understand solution which is discussed here makes sense for one call per session ?

Comment: @sll - this is for closing the connection immediately after the call returns (one call per session).

Comment: @cacho Making `DisposeSafely` private is certainly an option, and would avoid confusion. There may be use cases where someone would want to call it directly, but I can't come up with one offhand.

Comment: @truewill just for documentation, it is also important to mention that this method are thread-safe right?

Comment: @cacho It's static and doesn't access any global state, so it *should* be thread-safe - but that really depends on the proxy. Based on this it sounds like that's generally the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625367/is-wcf-clientbase-thread-safe If you're relying on it for your business I'd make sure, though.

Comment: In my opinion, the most correct solution would:

***1) Perform the Close/Abort pattern without a race condition
2) Handle the situation when the service operation throws exceptions
3) Handle the situations when both the Close and Abort methods throw exceptions
4) Handle asynchronous exceptions such as the ThreadAbortException***

`https://devzone.channeladam.com/articles/2014/07/how-to-call-wcf-service-properly/`

Answer (score 8):

@Marc Gravell

Wouldn't it be OK to use this:

```
public static TResult Using<T, TResult>(this T client, Func<T, TResult> work)
        where T : ICommunicationObject
{
    try
    {
        var result = work(client);

        client.Close();

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        client.Abort();

        throw;
    }
}
```

Or, the same thing `(Func<T, TResult>)` in case of `Service<IOrderService>.Use`

These would make returning variables easier.

Comment: +1 @MarcGravell I think your answer 'could do better' too :P (and the action one can be implemented in terms of a Func with a null return). This whole page is a mess - I'd go formulate a unified one and comment on dups if I envisaged using WCF any time this decade...

Answer (score 7):

Below is an enhanced version of the source from [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/573872/3312) and extended to cache multiple channel factories and attempt to look up the endpoint in the configuration file by contract name.

It uses .NET 4 (specifically: contravariance, LINQ, `var`):

```
/// <summary>
/// Delegate type of the service method to perform.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="proxy">The service proxy.</param>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of service to use.</typeparam>
internal delegate void UseServiceDelegate<in T>(T proxy);

/// <summary>
/// Wraps using a WCF service.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of service to use.</typeparam>
internal static class Service<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A dictionary to hold looked-up endpoint names.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly IDictionary<Type, string> cachedEndpointNames = new Dictionary<Type, string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// A dictionary to hold created channel factories.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, ChannelFactory<T>> cachedFactories =
        new Dictionary<string, ChannelFactory<T>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses the specified code block.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="codeBlock">The code block.</param>
    internal static void Use(UseServiceDelegate<T> codeBlock)
    {
        var factory = GetChannelFactory();
        var proxy = (IClientChannel)factory.CreateChannel();
        var success = false;

        try
        {
            using (proxy)
            {
                codeBlock((T)proxy);
            }

            success = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                proxy.Abort();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the channel factory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The channel factory.</returns>
    private static ChannelFactory<T> GetChannelFactory()
    {
        lock (cachedFactories)
        {
            var endpointName = GetEndpointName();

            if (cachedFactories.ContainsKey(endpointName))
            {
                return cachedFactories[endpointName];
            }

            var factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(endpointName);

            cachedFactories.Add(endpointName, factory);
            return factory;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The name of the endpoint.</returns>
    private static string GetEndpointName()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var fullName = type.FullName;

        lock (cachedFactories)
        {
            if (cachedEndpointNames.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                return cachedEndpointNames[type];
            }

            var serviceModel = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).SectionGroups["system.serviceModel"] as ServiceModelSectionGroup;

            if ((serviceModel != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
            {
                foreach (var endpointName in serviceModel.Client.Endpoints.Cast<ChannelEndpointElement>().Where(endpoint => fullName.EndsWith(endpoint.Contract)).Select(endpoint => endpoint.Name))
                {
                    cachedEndpointNames.Add(type, endpointName);
                    return endpointName;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find endpoint element for type '" + fullName + "' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `UseServiceDelegate<T>` instead of `Action<T>` ?

Comment: The only reason I can think that the original author did so was to have a strongly-typed delegate the developer would know belongs to calling a service. But, as far as I can see, `Action<T>` works just as well.

Answer (score 7):

**What is this?**

This is the CW version of the accepted answer but with (what I consider complete) Exception handling included.

The accepted answer references [this website that is no longer around](http://web.archive.org/web/20100703123454/http://old.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Indisposable+-+WCF+Gotcha+1.aspx).  To save you trouble, I am including the most relevant parts here.  In addition, I modified it slightly to include [exception retry handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048856/328397) to handle those pesky network timeouts.

**Simple WCF Client Usage**

Once you generate your client side proxy, this is all you need to implement it.

```
Service<IOrderService>.Use(orderService=>
{
  orderService.PlaceOrder(request);
});
```

**ServiceDelegate.cs**

Add this file to your solution.  No changes are needed to this file, unless you want to alter the number of retries or what exceptions you want to handle.

```
public delegate void UseServiceDelegate<T>(T proxy);

public static class Service<T>
{
    public static ChannelFactory<T> _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(""); 

    public static void Use(UseServiceDelegate<T> codeBlock)
    {
        IClientChannel proxy = (IClientChannel)_channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        bool success = false;


       Exception mostRecentEx = null;
       int millsecondsToSleep = 1000;

       for(int i=0; i<5; i++)  // Attempt a maximum of 5 times 
       {
           try
           {
               codeBlock((T)proxy);
               proxy.Close();
               success = true; 
               break;
           }

           // The following is typically thrown on the client when a channel is terminated due to the server closing the connection.
           catch (ChannelTerminatedException cte)
           {
              mostRecentEx = cte;
               proxy.Abort();
               //  delay (backoff) and retry 
               Thread.Sleep(millsecondsToSleep  * (i + 1)); 
           }

           // The following is thrown when a remote endpoint could not be found or reached.  The endpoint may not be found or 
           // reachable because the remote endpoint is down, the remote endpoint is unreachable, or because the remote network is unreachable.
           catch (EndpointNotFoundException enfe)
           {
              mostRecentEx = enfe;
               proxy.Abort();
               //  delay (backoff) and retry 
               Thread.Sleep(millsecondsToSleep * (i + 1)); 
           }

           // The following exception that is thrown when a server is too busy to accept a message.
           catch (ServerTooBusyException stbe)
           {
              mostRecentEx = stbe;
               proxy.Abort();

               //  delay (backoff) and retry 
               Thread.Sleep(millsecondsToSleep * (i + 1)); 
           }
           catch (TimeoutException timeoutEx)
           {
               mostRecentEx = timeoutEx;
               proxy.Abort();

               //  delay (backoff) and retry 
               Thread.Sleep(millsecondsToSleep * (i + 1)); 
           } 
           catch (CommunicationException comException)
           {
               mostRecentEx = comException;
               proxy.Abort();

               //  delay (backoff) and retry 
               Thread.Sleep(millsecondsToSleep * (i + 1)); 
           }
           catch(Exception )
           {
                // rethrow any other exception not defined here
                // You may want to define a custom Exception class to pass information such as failure count, and failure type
                proxy.Abort();
                throw ;  
           }
       }
       if (success == false && mostRecentEx != null) 
       { 
           proxy.Abort();
           throw new Exception("WCF call failed after 5 retries.", mostRecentEx );
       }

    }
}
```

PS: I've made this post a community wiki.  I won't collect "points" from this answer, but prefer you upvote it if you agree with the implementation, or edit it to make it better.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your characterization of this answer. It's the CW version with [_your_ idea of exception handling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9489503/76337) added.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - True (my concept of exception handling).  Let me know of any exceptions I'm missing or am mis-handling.

Comment: What's about success variable? It needs add to source code: if (success) return; ??

Comment: If the first call throws and the 2nd succeed mostRecentEx won't be null so you are throwing an exception that failed 5 retries anyways. or am I missing something? I don't see where you clear the mostRecentEx if on a 2nd,3rd,4th or 5th try succeeded. Also don't see a return o succeed. I should be missing something here, but this code won't run always 5 times if no exception is thrown ?

Comment: @Bart - I added `success == false` to the final if statement

Comment: being that there is a flavor of exponential back-off and retry, would adding the Enterprise Library Transient Fault Application Block be valuable?

Comment: In this reference `https://devzone.channeladam.com/articles/2014/07/how-to-call-wcf-service-properly/`, the most correct solution would:

***1) Perform the Close/Abort pattern without a race condition
2) Handle the situation when the service operation throws exceptions
3) Handle the situations when both the Close and Abort methods throw exceptions
4) Handle asynchronous exceptions such as the ThreadAbortException***

- **`What's about it?`**

Answer (score 5):

A wrapper like this would work:

```
public class ServiceClientWrapper<ServiceType> : IDisposable
{
    private ServiceType _channel;
    public ServiceType Channel
    {
        get { return _channel; }
    }

    private static ChannelFactory<ServiceType> _channelFactory;

    public ServiceClientWrapper()
    {
        if(_channelFactory == null)
             // Given that the endpoint name is the same as FullName of contract.
            _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceType>(typeof(T).FullName);
        _channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        ((IChannel)_channel).Open();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            ((IChannel)_channel).Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ((IChannel)_channel).Abort();
            // TODO: Insert logging
        }
    }
}
```

That should enable you to write code like:

```
ResponseType response = null;
using(var clientWrapper = new ServiceClientWrapper<IService>())
{
    var request = ...
    response = clientWrapper.Channel.MyServiceCall(request);
}
// Use your response object.
```

The wrapper could of course catch more exceptions if that is required, but the principle remains the same.

Comment: I remember discussion regarding Dispose not being called under certain conditions... resulting in a memory leak w/WCF.

Comment: I'm not sure it was resulting in memory leaks but the problem is this. When you call `Dispose` on a IChannel it could throw an exception if the channel is in a faulted state, this is a problem since Microsoft specify that `Dispose` should never throw. So what the code above does is handling the case when `Close` throws an exception. If `Abort` throws it might be something seriously wrong. I wrote a blog post about it last December: http://blog.tomasjansson.com/2010/12/disposible-wcf-client-wrapper/

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) or are using an autogenerated client (Service Reference), then you can simple use a wrapper to manage the closing and let the [GC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) take the clientbase when it is in a safe state that will not throw any exception. The GC will call Dispose in serviceclient, and this will call `Close`. Since it is alread closed, it cannot cause any damage. I am using this without problems in production code.

```
public class AutoCloseWcf : IDisposable
{

    private ICommunicationObject CommunicationObject;

    public AutoDisconnect(ICommunicationObject CommunicationObject)
    {
        this.CommunicationObject = CommunicationObject;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (CommunicationObject == null)
            return;
        try {
            if (CommunicationObject.State != CommunicationState.Faulted) {
                CommunicationObject.Close();
            } else {
                CommunicationObject.Abort();
            }
        } catch (CommunicationException ce) {
            CommunicationObject.Abort();
        } catch (TimeoutException toe) {
            CommunicationObject.Abort();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CommunicationObject.Abort();
            //Perhaps log this

        } finally {
            CommunicationObject = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you are accessing the server, you create the client and use `using` in the autodisconect:

```
var Ws = new ServiceClient("netTcpEndPointName");
using (new AutoCloseWcf(Ws)) {

    Ws.Open();

    Ws.Test();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used Castle dynamic proxy to solve the Dispose() issue, and also implemented auto-refreshing the channel when it is in an unusable state.  To use this you must create a new interface that inherits your service contract and IDisposable.  The dynamic proxy implements this interface and wraps a WCF channel:

```
Func<object> createChannel = () =>
    ChannelFactory<IHelloWorldService>
        .CreateChannel(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(uri));
var factory = new WcfProxyFactory();
var proxy = factory.Create<IDisposableHelloWorldService>(createChannel);
proxy.HelloWorld();
```

I like this since you can inject WCF services without consumers needing to worry about any details of WCF.  And there's no added cruft like the other solutions.

Have a look at the code, it's actually pretty simple:
[WCF Dynamic Proxy](https://github.com/JayDouglass/WcfProxy/blob/master/WcfProxy.Tests/WcfProxyTests.cs)

Answer (score 4):

Use an extension method:

```
public static class CommunicationObjectExtensions
{
    public static TResult MakeSafeServiceCall<TResult, TService>(this TService client, Func<TService, TResult> method) where TService : ICommunicationObject
    {
        TResult result;

        try
        {
            result = method(client);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException)
            {
                client.Abort(); // Don't care about these exceptions. The call has completed anyway.
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                client.Abort(); // Don't care about these exceptions. The call has completed anyway.
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                client.Abort();
                throw;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Summary

Using the techniques described in this answer one can consume a WCF service in a using block with the following syntax:

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>("");

var serviceHelper = new ServiceHelper<IMyService>(channelFactory);
var proxy = serviceHelper.CreateChannel();
using (proxy as IDisposable)
{
    proxy.DoWork();
}
```

You can of course adapt this even further to achieve a more concise programming model specific to your situation - but the point is that we can create an implementation of `IMyService` reprenting the channel which correctly implements the disposable pattern.

---

### Details

All the answers given thus far address the problem of getting around the "bug" in the WCF Channel implemention of `IDisposable`.  The answer that seems to offer the most concise programming model (allowing you to use the `using` block to dispose on unmanaged resources) is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4376544/2382536) - where the proxy is modifed to implement `IDisposable` with a bug-free implementation.  The problem with this approach is maintainability - we have to re-implement this functionality for ever proxy we use.  On a variation of this answer we will see how we can use *composition* rather than inheritance to make this technique generic.

#### First Attempt

There seem to various implementations for the `IDisposable` implementation, but for sake of argument we will use an adaption of that used by the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573925/2382536).

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();
}

public class ProxyDisposer : IDisposable
{
    private IClientChannel _clientChannel;


    public ProxyDisposer(IClientChannel clientChannel)
    {
        _clientChannel = clientChannel;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var success = false;
        try
        {
            _clientChannel.Close();
            success = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
                _clientChannel.Abort();
            _clientChannel = null;
        }
    }
}

public class ProxyWrapper : IMyService, IDisposable
{
    private IMyService _proxy;
    private IDisposable _proxyDisposer;

    public ProxyWrapper(IMyService proxy, IDisposable disposable)
    {
        _proxy = proxy;
        _proxyDisposer = disposable;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        _proxy.DoWork();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _proxyDisposer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Armed with the above classes we can now write

```
public class ServiceHelper
{
    private readonly ChannelFactory<IMyService> _channelFactory;

    public ServiceHelper(ChannelFactory<IMyService> channelFactory )
    {
        _channelFactory = channelFactory;
    }

    public IMyService CreateChannel()
    {
        var channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        var channelDisposer = new ProxyDisposer(channel as IClientChannel);
        return new ProxyWrapper(channel, channelDisposer);
    }
}
```

This allows us to consume our service using the `using` block:

```
ServiceHelper serviceHelper = ...;
var proxy = serviceHelper.CreateChannel();
using (proxy as IDisposable)
{
    proxy.DoWork();
}
```

#### Making this generic

All we have done so far is to reformulate [Tomas' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4376544/2382536).  What prevents this code from being generic is the fact that `ProxyWrapper` class has to be re-implemented for every service contract we want.  We will now look at a class that allows us to create this type dynamically using IL:

```
public class ServiceHelper<T>
{
    private readonly ChannelFactory<T> _channelFactory;

    private static readonly Func<T, IDisposable, T> _channelCreator;

    static ServiceHelper()
    {
        /** 
         * Create a method that can be used generate the channel. 
         * This is effectively a compiled verion of new ProxyWrappper(channel, channelDisposer) for our proxy type
         * */
        var assemblyName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var an = new AssemblyName(assemblyName);
        var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName);

        var proxyType = CreateProxyType(moduleBuilder, typeof(T), typeof(IDisposable));

        var channelCreatorMethod = new DynamicMethod("ChannelFactory", typeof(T),
            new[] { typeof(T), typeof(IDisposable) });

        var ilGen = channelCreatorMethod.GetILGenerator();
        var proxyVariable = ilGen.DeclareLocal(typeof(T));
        var disposableVariable = ilGen.DeclareLocal(typeof(IDisposable));
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, proxyVariable);
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, disposableVariable);
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, proxyType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(T), typeof(IDisposable) }));
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        _channelCreator =
            (Func<T, IDisposable, T>)channelCreatorMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, IDisposable, T>));

    }

    public ServiceHelper(ChannelFactory<T> channelFactory)
    {
        _channelFactory = channelFactory;
    }

    public T CreateChannel()
    {
        var channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        var channelDisposer = new ProxyDisposer(channel as IClientChannel);
        return _channelCreator(channel, channelDisposer);
    }

   /**
    * Creates a dynamic type analogous to ProxyWrapper, implementing T and IDisposable.
    * This method is actually more generic than this exact scenario.
    * */
    private static Type CreateProxyType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder, params Type[] interfacesToInjectAndImplement)
    {
        TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);

        var typeFields = interfacesToInjectAndImplement.ToDictionary(tf => tf,
            tf => tb.DefineField("_" + tf.Name, tf, FieldAttributes.Private));

        #region Constructor

        var constructorBuilder = tb.DefineConstructor(
            MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
            MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName,
            CallingConventions.Standard,
            interfacesToInjectAndImplement);

        var il = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(new Type[0]));

        for (var i = 1; i <= interfacesToInjectAndImplement.Length; i++)
        {
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, typeFields[interfacesToInjectAndImplement[i - 1]]);
        }
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        #endregion

        #region Add Interface Implementations

        foreach (var type in interfacesToInjectAndImplement)
        {
            tb.AddInterfaceImplementation(type);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Implement Interfaces

        foreach (var type in interfacesToInjectAndImplement)
        {
            foreach (var method in type.GetMethods())
            {
                var methodBuilder = tb.DefineMethod(method.Name,
                    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
                    MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.NewSlot,
                    method.ReturnType,
                    method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
                il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

                if (method.ReturnType == typeof(void))
                {
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, typeFields[type]);
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, method);
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                }
                else
                {
                    il.DeclareLocal(method.ReturnType);

                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, typeFields[type]);

                    var methodParameterInfos = method.GetParameters();
                    for (var i = 0; i < methodParameterInfos.Length; i++)
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, (i + 1));
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, method);

                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
                    var defineLabel = il.DefineLabel();
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, defineLabel);
                    il.MarkLabel(defineLabel);
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                }

                tb.DefineMethodOverride(methodBuilder, method);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        return tb.CreateType();
    }
}
```

With our new helper class we can now write

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>("");

var serviceHelper = new ServiceHelper<IMyService>(channelFactory);
var proxy = serviceHelper.CreateChannel();
using (proxy as IDisposable)
{
    proxy.DoWork();
}
```

Note that you could also use the same technique (with slight modifications) for auto-generated clients inheriting for `ClientBase<>` (instead of using `ChannelFactory<>`), or if you want to use a different implementation of `IDisposable` to close your channel.

Answer (score 2):

I like this way of closing connection:

```
var client = new ProxyClient();
try
{
    ...
    client.Close();
}
finally
{
    if(client.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
        client.Abort();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Our system architecture often uses the [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) framework to create instances of ClientBase so there's no sure way to enforce that the other developers even use `using{}` blocks. In order to make it as fool-proof as possible, I made this custom class that extends ClientBase, and handles closing down the channel on dispose, or on finalize in case someone doesn't explicitly dispose of the Unity created instance.

There is also stuff that needed to be done in the constructor to set up the channel for custom credentials and stuff, so that's in here too...

```
public abstract class PFServer2ServerClientBase<TChannel> : ClientBase<TChannel>, IDisposable where TChannel : class
{
    private bool disposed = false;

    public PFServer2ServerClientBase()
    {
        // Copy information from custom identity into credentials, and other channel setup...
    }

    ~PFServer2ServerClientBase()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            try
            {
                    if (this.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                        this.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (this.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    this.Abort();
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then a client can simply:

```
internal class TestClient : PFServer2ServerClientBase<ITest>, ITest
{
    public string TestMethod(int value)
    {
        return base.Channel.TestMethod(value);
    }
}
```

And the caller can do any of these:

```
public SomeClass
{
    [Dependency]
    public ITest test { get; set; }

    // Not the best, but should still work due to finalizer.
    public string Method1(int value)
    {
        return this.test.TestMethod(value);
    }

    // The good way to do it
    public string Method2(int value)
    {
        using(ITest t = unityContainer.Resolve<ITest>())
        {
            return t.TestMethod(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never make use of the parameter disposing in your Dispose method

Comment: @Chad - I was following Microsoft's common Finalize/Dispose design pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28VS.71%29.aspx  It is true that I am not using the variable though, because I don't need to do any different cleanup between a normal dispose and a finalize.  It could be rewritten to just have Finalize call Dispose() and move the code from Dispose(bool) to Dispose().

Comment: Finalizers add overhead, and aren't deterministic. I avoid them whenever possible. You can use Unity's automatic factories to inject delegates and put those in using blocks, or (better) hide the create/call/dispose service behavior behind a method on an injected interface. Each call to the dependency creates the proxy, calls it, and disposes of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have written [a simple base class](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/WcfClientBase) that handles this. It's available as a [NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/WcfClientBase) and it's quite easy to use.

```
//MemberServiceClient is the class generated by SvcUtil
public class MemberServiceManager : ServiceClientBase<MemberServiceClient>
{
    public User GetUser(int userId)
    {
        return PerformServiceOperation(client => client.GetUser(userId));
    }

    //you can also check if any error occured if you can't throw exceptions       
    public bool TryGetUser(int userId, out User user)
    {
        return TryPerformServiceOperation(c => c.GetUser(userId), out user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any updates for VS2013-.net 4.5.1 ? any options for Retry like http://stackoverflow.com/a/9370880/206730? –

Comment: @Kiquenet I'm not working on WCF anymore. If you send me a pull request, I can merge it and update the package.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Service<TChannel>
{
    public static ChannelFactory<TChannel> ChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<TChannel>("*");

    public static TReturn Use<TReturn>(Func<TChannel,TReturn> codeBlock)
    {
        var proxy = (IClientChannel)ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        var success = false;
        try
        {
            var result = codeBlock((TChannel)proxy);
            proxy.Close();
            success = true;
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                proxy.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it allows to write return statements nicely:

```
return Service<IOrderService>.Use(orderService => 
{ 
    return orderService.PlaceOrder(request); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, here's a VB.NET translation of the accepted answer (below). I've refined it a bit for brevity, combining some of the tips by others in this thread.

I admit it's off-topic for the originating tags (C#), but as I wasn't able to find a VB.NET version of this fine solution I assume that others will be looking as well. The Lambda translation can be a bit tricky, so I'd like to save someone the trouble.

Note that this particular implementation provides the ability to configure the `ServiceEndpoint` at runtime.

---

**Code:**

```
Namespace Service
  Public NotInheritable Class Disposable(Of T)
    Public Shared ChannelFactory As New ChannelFactory(Of T)(Service)

    Public Shared Sub Use(Execute As Action(Of T))
      Dim oProxy As IClientChannel

      oProxy = ChannelFactory.CreateChannel

      Try
        Execute(oProxy)
        oProxy.Close()

      Catch
        oProxy.Abort()
        Throw

      End Try
    End Sub



    Public Shared Function Use(Of TResult)(Execute As Func(Of T, TResult)) As TResult
      Dim oProxy As IClientChannel

      oProxy = ChannelFactory.CreateChannel

      Try
        Use = Execute(oProxy)
        oProxy.Close()

      Catch
        oProxy.Abort()
        Throw

      End Try
    End Function



    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Service As ServiceEndpoint
      Get
        Return New ServiceEndpoint(
          ContractDescription.GetContract(
            GetType(T),
            GetType(Action(Of T))),
          New BasicHttpBinding,
          New EndpointAddress(Utils.WcfUri.ToString))
      End Get
    End Property
  End Class
End Namespace
```

**Usage:**

```
Public ReadOnly Property Jobs As List(Of Service.Job)
  Get
    Disposable(Of IService).Use(Sub(Client) Jobs = Client.GetJobs(Me.Status))
  End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Jobs As List(Of Service.Job)
  Get
    Return Disposable(Of IService).Use(Function(Client) Client.GetJobs(Me.Status))
  End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add implementation of Service from [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573925/722552) for case of using ServiceClient instead of ChannelFactory.

```
public interface IServiceConnector<out TServiceInterface>
{
    void Connect(Action<TServiceInterface> clientUsage);
    TResult Connect<TResult>(Func<TServiceInterface, TResult> channelUsage);
}

internal class ServiceConnector<TService, TServiceInterface> : IServiceConnector<TServiceInterface>
    where TServiceInterface : class where TService : ClientBase<TServiceInterface>, TServiceInterface, new()
{
    public TResult Connect<TResult>(Func<TServiceInterface, TResult> channelUsage)
    {
        var result = default(TResult);
        Connect(channel =>
        {
            result = channelUsage(channel);
        });
        return result;
    }

    public void Connect(Action<TServiceInterface> clientUsage)
    {
        if (clientUsage == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("clientUsage");
        }
        var isChanneldClosed = false;
        var client = new TService();
        try
        {
            clientUsage(client);
            client.Close();
            isChanneldClosed = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!isChanneldClosed)
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I referred few answers on this post and customized it as per my needs.

I wanted the ability to do something with WCF client before using it so the `DoSomethingWithClient()` method.

```
public interface IServiceClientFactory<T>
{
    T DoSomethingWithClient();
}
public partial class ServiceClient : IServiceClientFactory<ServiceClient>
{
    public ServiceClient DoSomethingWithClient()
    {
        var client = this;
        // do somthing here as set client credentials, etc.
        //client.ClientCredentials = ... ;
        return client;
    }
}
```

Here is the helper class:

```
public static class Service<TClient>
    where TClient : class, ICommunicationObject, IServiceClientFactory<TClient>, new()
{
    public static TReturn Use<TReturn>(Func<TClient, TReturn> codeBlock)
    {
        TClient client = default(TClient);
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            client = new TClient().DoSomethingWithClient();
            TReturn result = codeBlock(client);
            client.Close();
            success = true;
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success && client != null)
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I can use it as:

```
string data = Service<ServiceClient>.Use(x => x.GetData(7));
```

Comment: What's about Client constructor using binding and endpoing ? TClient(binding, endpoing)

Answer (score 0):

I have my own wrapper for a channel which implements Dispose as follows:

```
public void Dispose()
{
        try
        {
            if (channel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                channel.Abort();
            }
            else
            {
                channel.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (CommunicationException)
        {
            channel.Abort();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            channel.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            channel.Abort();
            throw;
        }
}
```

This seems to work well and allows a using block to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The following helper allows to call `void` and non-void methods. Usage:

```
var calculator = new WcfInvoker<CalculatorClient>(() => new CalculatorClient());
var sum = calculator.Invoke(c => c.Sum(42, 42));
calculator.Invoke(c => c.RebootComputer());
```

The class itself is:

```
public class WcfInvoker<TService>
    where TService : ICommunicationObject
{
    readonly Func<TService> _clientFactory;

    public WcfInvoker(Func<TService> clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public T Invoke<T>(Func<TService, T> action)
    {
        var client = _clientFactory();
        try
        {
            var result = action(client);
            client.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            client.Abort();
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Invoke(Action<TService> action)
    {
        Invoke<object>(client =>
        {
            action(client);
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the client's Dispose() without the need to generate a proxy class based on ClientBase, also without the need to [manage channel creation and caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh314046(v=vs.110).aspx)!  (Note that WcfClient is not an ABSTRACT class and is based on ClientBase)

```
// No need for a generated proxy class
//using (WcfClient<IOrderService> orderService = new WcfClient<IOrderService>())
//{
//    results = orderService.GetProxy().PlaceOrder(input);
//}

public class WcfClient<TService> : ClientBase<TService>, IDisposable
    where TService : class
{
    public WcfClient()
    {
    }

    public WcfClient(string endpointConfigurationName) :
        base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public WcfClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) :
        base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public WcfClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
        base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public WcfClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
        base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    protected virtual void OnDispose()
    {
        bool success = false;

        if ((base.Channel as IClientChannel) != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((base.Channel as IClientChannel).State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    (base.Channel as IClientChannel).Close();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!success)
                {
                    (base.Channel as IClientChannel).Abort();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public TService GetProxy()
    {
        return this.Channel as TService;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        OnDispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My method of doing this has been to create an inherited class that explicitly implements IDisposable. This is useful for folks who use the gui to add the service reference ( Add Service Reference ). I just drop this class in the project making the service reference and use it instead of the default client:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using MyApp.MyService; // The name you gave the service namespace

namespace MyApp.Helpers.Services
{
    public class MyServiceClientSafe : MyServiceClient, IDisposable
    {
        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            if (State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                Abort();
            }
            else if (State != CommunicationState.Closed)
            {
                Close();
            }

            // Further error checks and disposal logic as desired..
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This is just a simple implementation of dispose, you can implement more complex dispose logic if you like.

You can then replace all your calls made with the regular service client with the safe clients, like this:

```
using (MyServiceClientSafe client = new MyServiceClientSafe())
{
    var result = client.MyServiceMethod();
}
```

I like this solution as it does not require me to have access to the Interface definitions and I can use the `using` statement as I would expect while allowing my code to look more or less the same.

You will still need to handle the exceptions which can be thrown as pointed out in other comments in this thread.

Answer (score -2):

You could also use a `DynamicProxy` to extend the `Dispose()` method. This way you could do something like:

```
using (var wrapperdProxy = new Proxy<yourProxy>())
{
   // Do whatever and dispose of Proxy<yourProxy> will be called and work properly.
}
```