# Should I check if already closed before calling Close() on a WCF Service?

Tags: wcf

Before I call `Close()` on my WCF service, should I check to see if it is not already closed?

i.e.

```
myWCFService.State != System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Closed
```

My code looks like:

```
MyServiceClient myWCFClient = null;

try
{
  myWCFClient = new .....();
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
   myWCFClient.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A WCF client is disposable, so *except for a few caveats* you can use `using`:

```
using(MyClient client = new MyClient()) {
    client.DoStuff();
    // etc
}
```

But there is a big problem with this; the `Dispose` on the WCF client actually throws if it is faulted (losing the original exception). There is a good workaround, [here](http://www.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Indisposable+-+WCF+Gotcha+1.aspx), or I've blogged on this [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question: [What is the best workaround for the WCF client `using` block issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue) Although it isn't word for word what you are looking for, I think his examples will help you out.