# Underlying connection closed exception thrown in web service call

Tags: c#, asmx, webservice-client

I know this question has been asked before, and many suggestions have been made, but I have tried all of them and none worked, so I am trying to see if anyone has extra knowledge on this matter.

Scenario:
I have a console application in which I have added a web reference to an ASMX web service.
In the console app I have generated a derived class like this:

```
public class OverridenWebRequestReporting : webservice.Reporting
{
    public OverridenWebRequestReporting(string addr)
        : base(addr)
    {
    }

    protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

The call to the web service method is the following:

```
        OverridenWebRequestReporting reportingService = new OverridenWebRequestReporting("http://some_web_location_where_the_service_is_deployed/Reporting.svc");

        CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();

        cache.Add(new Uri("http://some_web_location_where_the_service_is_deployed/Reporting.svc"), "NTLM",new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"));

        reportingService.Credentials = cache;

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (reportingService)
        {
            try
            {
                dt = reportingService.GetAllDocumentsMetadataFromSP("someString", "anotherString");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Using the debugger, I can clearly see that the call is made, and it returns a valid datatable, but when the last return statement is made, the code enters the catch block, with an exception of "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server." being thrown

Framework is 4.5.

Any suggestions in what else can I do to prevent the exception from being thrown?

Comment: Sometimes when you try adding the service as a service reference, the code generator throws the same exception, but with a detailed message. My guess is that you have something in your return value that can not be serialized to the client or you access a lazy variable that is disposed before the return is complete.

Comment: The console app is just a "testing environment". It's an old legacy. I could add it simply as a service reference. Do you think this might be negatively impacting the calls?

Comment: I just have an asmx that is added as a web reference. The reason (it took me a while to remember this :P) is that I cannot add a reference to System.ServiceModel to my app.

Comment: Ok, Can you tell me the return type of the value send to the client?

Comment: It's DataTable. Could this be a problem? Should any serialization take place? I must admit, I am not very familiar with web services. The method signature (in the service) is: `public System.Data.DataTable GetAllDocumentsMetadataFromSP(string username, string library)`

Comment: Everything send to the client must be serializable, because the client must know the rules to rebuild the data to the proper data type. I do not think a datatable is serializable. Perhaps returning the result as a concattenated string to test if no exception is thrown anymore will put you on the right track.

Comment: Well, this went well :) you were right about the DataTable. the string returned well, with everything in it. What would the solution be if I wanted to transport something like a datatable through to the client? A datacontract of some sort?

Comment: Yes that would be a solution, however I have very limited knowledge about asmx, I always had the luxury of a service reference.

Comment: `DataTable` serializes just fine. There are certain rules you have to follow though, such as setting the `TableName` property on the server side (this one has bit me the most in the past).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a combination of changes:

1) Adding, as Kirill suggested, a name to the datatable

2) Using `dt.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, false);` in the service, to generate an XML string

3) Using

```
using (StringReader r = new StringReader(XMLSerializedResult))
        {
            dt.ReadXml(XmlReader.Create(r));
        }
```

in the client to deserialize the XML  string.

Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Closing WCF connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400010/closing-wcf-connection). Basically this happens when Dispose is called by the using block. Solution: skip using and call .Close or .Abort as needed.

MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

Comment: I have tried removing the using block (actually, it wasn't there in the beginning) but it still hits the catch block. I just added the using block hoping that this would solve the problem. It's not the case...