# WCF error - The system hit the limit set for throttle 'MaxConcurrentSessions'

Tags: wcf, timeout, asp.net-2.0

I have an asp.net app that calls a WCF service. I've been having intermittent timeouts for a while so I decided to create a trace log. After getting a timeout I found the message below in the log file:

> The system hit the limit set for
>   throttle 'MaxConcurrentSessions'.
>   Limit for this throttle was set to 10.
>   Throttle value can be changed by
>   modifying attribute
>   'maxConcurrentSessions' in
>   serviceThrottle element or by
>   modifying 'MaxConcurrentSessions'
>   property on behavior
>   ServiceThrottlingBehavior.

The thing is though I'm closing the client connection each time so I don't understand why the concurrent sessions are adding up. Below is a typical call that I make:

```
    try
    {
        //create proxy
        client = new CAEServiceContractClient();

        response = client.GetSecurityRecords(item); 
        totalRecords = response.TotalRecords;

        securityListView.DataSource = response.SecurityItemColl; 
        securityListView.DataBind();

        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
        success = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!success)
        {
            client.Abort();
        }
    }
```

So my question is, why isn't the session being destroyed once I execute client.Close()?

TIA.

Comment: What bidning do you use? How many clients access your site when error occures?

Comment: @Ladislav I will check tomorrow but I'm pretty sure it's wsHttpBinding

Comment: @Ladislav We are still in development so it is only me accesing the service when the error occurs.

Comment: If your client closing doesn't work it could be easily reproducible. Call your service 10 times in single session.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `success` declared in the above code as a local variable, nor do I see you setting it to false. Could it be a class member that is being set to `true` on the first successful call and then staying that way?

In any case, that whole code block can be rewritten to be simpler to understand (and less bug-prone) like this:

```
using (var client = new CAEServiceContractClient())
{
    response = client.GetSecurityRecords(item); 
    totalRecords = response.TotalRecords;

    securityListView.DataSource = response.SecurityItemColl; 
    securityListView.DataBind();
}
```

The `using` statement ensures that when the `using` block has completed (normally or abnormally by an exception), the `client` variable will be disposed (`.Dispose()` will be called), thus closing the connection.

**EDIT:** As Ladislav Mrnka pointed out, the `.Dispose()` method of `ClientBase` has a bad habit of throwing an exception in some cases. Make sure to implement the `.Dispose()` method in your partial `CAEServiceContractClient` class as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue/1424384#1424384).

Comment: @Allon: This is WCF anti-pattern! http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/

Comment: @Ladislav: It's not an anti-pattern, it's simply bad design of the `ClientBase` class (read the first three comments of the article you linked). But thanks for bringing it to my attention, I didn't know about it. I still like [Matt's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue/1424384#1424384) better.

Comment: @Allon: Yes that suggestion is very nice solution. I was not able to find it when posting my first comment. Here is official MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

Comment: @Allon I have declared 'bool success = false' outside that block of code I just didn't show it above

Comment: @Ciaran: OK, but since it doesn't have a catch block, if an exception is raised it won't be set to false.

Comment: @Allon: The success variable is false by default, it's only set to true when client.Close is called. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Allon: Also, is try/catch/finally sufficient to handle the closing of the proxy? Why would we go to the trouble of adding a .Dispose method in the CAEServiceContractClient class  if try/catch/finally works? Thnx for the help.

Comment: @Ciaran: If `success` is a local variable, then there's problem. If it's a field or property, then you need to set it to false. As for try-catch-finally, it is sufficient, but only if you do it correctly. It is very easy to get it wrong, and why I think the `using` statement is much better in general, and only somewhat better with WCF's `ClientBase` in particular (due to it throwing exceptions when disposing).