# AddressAlreadyInUseException. Port is not released

Tags: c#, wcf

in C# using WCF I have more than once experienced that a port is not released when the program has ended. When I use tcpview I see the port is in state “listening” and process is “non-existent”.

How can this happen, when the process is not running any more?

I can't even close it via tcpview. How do i close the connection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue

Comment: It would seem your wcf service is not properly disposed of? what kind of binding are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, do you manually call Close() your client everywhere ?
Is there a possibility a Close could slip if the program ended in an unexpected way ?

By the way, I think you can close zombie connections with [currport](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html)

Comment: yes it could be missed. It is a .net console program which sometimes is forced killed by a scheduler/os.