# WCF wrap proxy client

Tags: wcf, proxy, client

I have many web method in my projects that used in client application. ]

I don't want write code something like this:

```
 using(ServiceClient sc = new ServiceClient())
    {
         //Invoke service methods        
         sc.Method1();
    }
```

instead, I want to write: `ServiceClient.Method1();` in that case all common operation which reffered to the proxy initialization, invoking method, disposing, exception processing will be inside ServiceClient. Of couse, i can wrap any of my web method with similar code or use reflection for retriving method by name, but maybe any other ways are exist?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Add Service Reference to generate ServiceClient...

First off, [it's not safe](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html) to wrap ServiceClient (which derives from ClientBase) in a using block. [Here is a stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue) that goes in depth.

Second, you can encapsulate the generated ServiceClient and create static methods that do what you are describing, but that's a lot of manual coding for very little benefit. I would instead encourage you to encapsulate the proxy creation, invocation, error handling, closing and disposing in a generic class. [This is a good example](http://old.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Indisposable+-+WCF+Gotcha+1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your "Method1" a static member of ServiceClient and then call `ServiceClient.Method1();`