# Problems with the Using Statement and WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, using-statement

I've been wrapping all the code that invoke WCF calls within an using statement in a thought that the object will be disposed properly. When I'm googling for an exception "Http service located at .. is too busy" I found this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx that says should not use using statement in typed proxies. Is that really true? I think I got a big code change (sigh). Is this problem comes only in typed proxies?

Sample code:

```
private ServiceClient proxy;

using(proxy = new ServiceClient("ConfigName", "http://serviceaddress//service.svc")){
    string result = proxy.Method();
}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue and also: http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/idisposable-and-wcf/

Comment: Interesting. I don't think you'll have issues if you use a binding such as basichttpbinding and create an instance on the server per call.

Comment: @BennyM: the same problems will possibly occur, regardless of what binding you use .....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The **core of the problem** is: at the end of your `using` block (which generally is a very good idea to have!), the WCF proxy will be disposed. However, during disposing of the WCF proxy, exceptions can occur - and those will cause the app to misbehave. Since this is done implicitly at the end of the `using` block, you might not even really see where the error occurs.

So typically, [Microsoft recommends a pattern something like this:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx)

```
private ServiceClient proxy;

try
{
    proxy = new ServiceClient("ConfigName", "http://serviceaddress//service.svc");
    string result = proxy.Method();
    proxy.Close();    
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
   // possibly log error, possibly clean up
   proxy.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
   // possibly log error, possibly clean up
   proxy.Abort();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   // possibly log error, possibly clean up
   proxy.Abort();
   throw;
}
```

You need to call the `proxy.Close()` method explicitly and be prepared to handle any exceptions that might occur from that call, too.

Comment: I like to confirm one thing, if the Close() throw exceptions then the connections are left open so after a period the service can't able to serve new requests rgt?

Comment: @Mark: unless you call `proxy.Abort()` after an exception happened - yes, then the proxy might linger around.....

Comment: but isn't the same situation apply for any object that implement Idisposable ?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the proxy operation and instantiation calls up in a class implementing `IDisposable`. When disposing, check the state property of the proxy and tidy up the channel before closing.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (this.MyProxy != null && this.MyProxy.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
    {
        this.MyProxy.Abort();
        this.MyProxy.Close();
        this.MyProxy = null;
    }
    // ...more tidyup conditions here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the approach from the comment from "Eric" on this blog (which is similar to another article: http://redcango.blogspot.com/2009/11/using-using-statement-with-wcf-proxy.htm):

"Personally, I like to create my own partial class for the client and override the Dispose() method. This allows me to use the ‘using’ block as I normally would.

```
public partial class SomeWCFServiceClient : IDisposable
{
  void IDisposable.Dispose()
  {
   if (this.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
   {
    this.Abort();
   }
   else
   {
     this.Close();
   }
  }
}
```