# Closing WCF connections using a static/centralized class

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, nettcpbinding

I want to begin implementing a better solution for closing my WCF connections throughout my code, as well as handle any issues with exceptions during that process. I plan on implementing the solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888238/wcf-closing-best-practice) but rather than duplicate this across my classes I'd like to write a static class that I can send my open connections to for closure and exception handling, like so:

```
public static class WCFManager
{
    public static void CloseConnection(ServiceClient serviceClient)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceClient.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException e)
        {
            var error = e.Message;
            serviceClient.Abort();
            //TODO: Log error for communication exception
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        {
            var error = e.Message;
            serviceClient.Abort();
            //TODO: Log error for timeout exception
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var error = e.Message;
            serviceClient.Abort();
            //TODO: Log error for exception
        }
    }
}
```

Where I am running into an issue is in the fact that I have many service client types and I am not sure what the base class is I should target for the WCFManager.CloseConnection() method to accept. Each service client seems to be a unique class and I can't find a suitable interface or base class among them. For example:

```
//Inside Class1:
var alphaServiceClient = new AlphaService.AlphaServiceClient();
alphaServiceClient.Open();
WCFManager.CloseConnection(alphaServiceClient); //<-- Requires AlphaServiceClient type

//Inside Class2:
var betaServiceClient = new BetaService.BetaServiceClient();
betaServiceClient.Open();
WCFManager.CloseConnection(betaServiceClient); //<-- Requires BetaServiceClient type
```

**Questions:**

**1:** I'd like to avoid creating an override of WCFManager.CloseConnection() for each service client type, but is this the only option I have?

**2:** Is this even a good option, or will passing the connection around cause more potential issues?

**3.** Since I am load balancing my WCF server across 2-4 servers, is closing the connection each time it is used the best option, or is creating a static reference to each ServiceClient once a better scenario (I am pretty sure it is not, but would love a second opinion on this!)

**FYI:** I'm using NetTcpBinding and am adding ServiceReferences within solution explorer.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1: I'd like to avoid creating an override of
>   WCFManager.CloseConnection() for each service client type, but is this
>   the only option I have?

All WCF proxies inherit from [`ICommunicationObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject(v=vs.110).aspx). That is in fact the interface that defines the Abort() and Close() methods. In order to call your method, always cast to `ICommunicationObject` first.

Also minor suggestion: What you are doing works even better as an extension method of `ICommunicationObject`. Then it becomes

```
((ICommunicationObject)alphaServiceClient).CloseConnection();
```

> 2: Is this even a good option, or will passing the connection around
>   cause more potential issues?

This is a helper method. Its hardly "passing around the connection". Its fine.

> 3. Since I am load balancing my WCF server across 2-4 servers, is closing the connection each time it is used the best option

Yes. Use the connection and close it.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the type of answer I was hoping for!