# Configure ASP.Net client for 3th party webservice secured with certificate & signature

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soap, .net-3.5, certificate

I'm trying to create a client for a **3th party webservice** from scratch.
I have a working solution in **soapUI** which uses a certificate with signatures like in the image below.

[image]

I'm **very new to SOA & SOAP** and my main question is how do I start with this and where by using **.NET 3.5 & ASP.Net**.
The service is linked to my project by using "Add service reference" but what now?

Comment: Please see the [wcf](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info) tag as a starting point.

Comment: I know what WCF is & already set one up  but I don't know how to configure the signature & certificate for the 3th party java webservice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem but encountered 10 problems since I'm new to it.

For example **"Timestamp must be signed error in response"**, you can read the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199181/timestamp-must-be-signed-error-in-response).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a disposal web service consumer class will be created for you in the namespace you provided when configuring the service reference.  The default namespace for such consumers will be under `ServiceReference1`, and the client will be named with the convention `WebServiceNameClient`. That consumer will have member methods representing all requests that can be invoked on the web service, for instance:

**C#**

```
My.Project.Root.ServiceReference1.WebServiceNameClient client = new My.Project.Root.ServiceReference1.WebServiceNameClient();
string action = "GET";
int id = 1;
var result = client.DoWebServiceWork(action, id);
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim client As New My.Project.Root.ServiceReference1.WebServiceNameClient()
Dim action As String = "GET"
Dim id As Integer = 1
Dim result = client.DoWebServiceWork(action, id)
```

Comment: -1: WCF client proxy classes are one of the very few places where you should not use `using`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue

Comment: @JohnSaunders Edited to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: I know how to use it but I don't know how to configure the signature & certificate.

Comment: Is this a client certificate installed for the local machine or current user's store?