# Timestamp must be signed error in response

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

For starters, I know you'd think this is a duplicate but if you read them you'll notice that some people say that deleting the timestamp will fix it and others tell otherwise.

I'm trying to connect to a Java SOAP Webservice with certificates by using **.Net 3.5** but when I receive the response it throws an error : **"The security header element 'Timestamp' with the 'Timestamp-984' id must be signed."**

```
var b = new CustomBinding();
b.Name = "AVbinding";
b.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
b.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
b.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
b.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement security = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
security.IncludeTimestamp = true;
security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12;
security.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToInitiator);
security.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient);
security.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;
security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15;
security.AllowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply = true;
security.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
security.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
security.RequireSignatureConfirmation = true;

security.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;

ExtensionElement extensionElement = new ExtensionElement();

b.Elements.Add(security);
b.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8));
HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBinding = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
b.Elements.Add(httpsBinding);

string certMapPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certMapPath + "\\_CERTNAME_", "X");
X509Certificate2 serCert = new X509Certificate2(certMapPath + "\\_CERTNAME2_.cer");
AsymmetricAlgorithm key = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
key.FromXmlString("_KEY_");
cert.PrivateKey = key;

client.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign;
```

Question is, what do I have to do?

My request :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="7d9e44cb-cecd-4c49-9a71-79a2ad04a2ec" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">63bde0b8-8953-41b8-b5c2-a69c712346b6</ActivityId>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo3dbGZWnrwhDouJE+VgKu4MAAAAAzmpHur/flUSUy0rxOVAJ8Nk4GsFjc6xOg46yQ3o0ZMQACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<o:BinarySecurityToken>
<!-- Removed-->
</o:BinarySecurityToken>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></SignatureMethod>
<Reference URI="#_2">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod>
<DigestValue>Z4OHoIS/bVCWIROLBFcxjfJuXv0ebA/SO8WQWuPTrQo=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
<Reference URI="#uuid-f52585e9-3358-46f6-8e9f-9a16b5c0f29b-1">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod>
<DigestValue>Pnp4gaKUnboMFE2LgLdsFzPBL+7fHqXacVg/MR7AS6c=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>NSE/peVOxXheXOqyNT1qx7uZPOhSms35fmJxlf4lBuODD9tz8/TCwzmAAdDArGwc6VJmdw1jVX5tNchYvAqignsPRgTwB+tSbMvUZ6UMwOgHZWRh8rXjYw34EhdEWWBzg0U1ves6ynY88vJW0oFyWiiFcNGkEuy140X7h/Ev+3I=</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference URI="#uuid-da5ccb9b-2c40-4ede-9079-c94abf912843-2"></o:Reference>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
<u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-f52585e9-3358-46f6-8e9f-9a16b5c0f29b-1">
<u:Created>2013-03-04T09:27:15.087Z</u:Created>
<u:Expires>2013-03-04T09:32:15.087Z</u:Expires>
</u:Timestamp>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body u:Id="_2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<getAvailabilityRequest xmlns="_url_">
<userID xmlns="">_UserID_</userID>
<password xmlns="">_pass_</password>
<requestID xmlns="">_request_</requestID>
<SystemIdentifier xmlns="">?</SystemIdentifier>
</getAvailabilityRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Response :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-932">
<wsu:Created>2013-03-04T09:27:24.013Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2013-03-04T09:32:24.013Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<!-- Removed-->
</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-930">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></ds:SignatureMethod>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-931">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>+/NJN562AUh5U5T4VXGRbdU28+JLmW2bdHg1gLf/SWg=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#SigConf-929">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>uzljMoX3dAm90+8P10b2/xE5OooNeP81NDtlefCBoc8=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>Fixb+0TnwQ2KfLqywusmwcKF8OvoBP/bLqIKfLadyV1U97+NZKzcMrSJjSD0a0sDhJZ+lo/KoHVE
KBY12ZZDP9xE+k9LHAlWZIq3a2gvBkTFR3p5NcYFQM4cbA/x/bvpEqDyzqYSoXnXMOG46DFn5klo
DO0PJkMiXKvLBhrCpZtM26AovD5WQlD694EeIXt4jey15zvGzKz88eNfHqNiYa1Wu2HuOTcnSJRv
hQKHmJKpDzn9+ZSohsULVR5xtGFQD7GWL6LLFEMqthD2a10KMan43Qd62SMUcB64o+l/M+l89+Oo
AbE0S2GXP3vvSa3ZoGduktWlyNlC7Qz/Iww0Qg==
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-83F04DBB53B92E8E1F1362389243499698">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STRId-83F04DBB53B92E8E1F1362389243499699" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Reference URI="#CertId-83F04DBB53B92E8E1F1362389243499697" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"></wsse:Reference>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<wsse11:SignatureConfirmation xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" Value="NSE/peVOxXheXOqyNT1qx7uZPOhSms35fmJxlf4lBuODD9tz8/TCwzmAAdDArGwc6VJmdw1jVX5tNchYvAqignsPRgTwB+tSbMvUZ6UMwOgHZWRh8rXjYw34EhdEWWBzg0U1ves6ynY88vJW0oFyWiiFcNGkEuy140X7h/Ev+3I=" wsu:Id="SigConf-929"></wsse11:SignatureConfirmation>
</wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-931">
<ns3:getAvailabilityResponse xmlns:ns3="_URL_" xmlns="">
<RequestID>_requestID_</RequestID>
<Status>Available</Status>
<Version>1.32.0</Version>
</ns3:getAvailabilityResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please publish the full request and response messages here (you can get them from Wcf log or Fiddler).
In general, if Wcf sends a signed timestamp, and the response contains a timestamp, then the response ts must be signed. There are various workarouns depending on the exact messages, including not sending a timestamp from the first place, or sending it via pushing it to the message in a handler, or removing the timestamp from the response.

Comment: Thx for reading!
I edited my post with the request & response but the 3th party service requires timestamps in the requests.
If I port it to 4.0 (because the hotfix isn't installable anymore) it tells me my key doesn't exists

Comment: EnableUnsecuredResponse means that the response is not secured at all. you would need to add a custome encoder to strip all security from the response to use that. this would mean the response will not be validated for signature at all, which may not be what you want (though can be ok if there is ssl or you do not care for some reason). Otherwise is it fair to say that the server requires the request to have a timestamp and to have it signed too, or it will not work? and then the server returns an unsigned timestamp in the response?

Comment: It won't work if we don't include any timestamps so there is no other option than stripping the responds I guess?

Comment: the question is if this will work if you send a timestamp but don't sign it. this may work since the server does not sign the response timestamp. the way to do it is to configure includeTimestamp=false so wcf does not emit/sign a timestamp. Then use a custom message encoder to push a timestamp that you create in there (be carefull not to change any signed message parts in the encoder). here are some encoder samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a great plan! I'll try to use an encoder, question is where do I add it? In the WriteMessage-method just before returning the message?

Comment: Unfortunately the timestamp I'm sending needs to be signed.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ok, if you're sending a signed timestamp wcf seems to require either a signed timestamp in response or no security at all.

Comment: well they return a timestampt that isn't signed but I'm using a custom text encoder at the moment to strip the timestamp out but how will I be able to sign the timestamp when I'm sending my request in the encode, any suggestions?

Thanks for your help man

Comment: My best suggestion is to ask them to sign the timestamp in the response or not to require the timestamp to be signed o the request. Otherwise you can either strip *all security* from the response, so you loose security validation (which may be ok if you have ssl for example) or you should implement the whole signature stack yourself via SignedXml. If anything you can send the signed timestamp as normal and on the response strip the security, but before that manually validate that the signature is valid so you will not loose this capability.

Comment: A long shot is to use requirements.OutgoingSignatureParts in order to remove the expectaion to sign the timestamp in the response I'm just not sure the Timestmap (being under the "security" element) can be managed there.