# Is it possible to get rid of the TClient generic type in the Service class

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, types

For WCF clients, I have a `IServiceProxyFactory` interface to set credentials.

```
public interface IServiceProxyFactory<T>
{
    T GetServiceProxy();
}

public class ServiceProxy1 : IServiceProxyFactory<ServiceClient1>
{
    public ServiceClient1 GetServiceProxy()
    {
        var client = new ServiceClient1();
        // set credentials here
        return client;
    }
}

public class ServiceProxy2 : IServiceProxyFactory<ServiceClient2> { 
    // ... 
}
```

From the question [What is the best workaround for the WCF client `using` block issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue), and I created a helper as follows:

```
public static class Service<TProxy, TClient>
    where TProxy : IServiceProxyFactory<TClient>, new()
    where TClient : ICommunicationObject
{
    public static IServiceProxyFactory<TClient> proxy = new TProxy();

    public static void Use(Action<TClient> codeBlock)
    {
        TClient client = default(TClient);
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            client = proxy.GetServiceProxy();
            codeBlock(client);
            ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
            success = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                ((ICommunicationObject)client).Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I use the helper as:

```
Service<ServiceProxy1, ServiceClient1>.Use(svc => svc.Method());
```

Question:

1. Is there a way where I can get rid of the `TClient` or `TProxy`**(updated)** type so that I can call using:

   ```
   Service<ServiceProxy1>.Use(svc => svc.Method());
   ```

   OR **(updated)**

   ```
   Service<ServiceClient1>.Use(svc => svc.Method());
   ```
2. Is there a better way than to use `ICommunicationObject` for `Close()` and `Abort()`?

Comment: Hmmm...can you change the constraint on the class to be IServiceProxy<ICommunicationObject>, remove TClient from the class signature, and add TClient and the constraint to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it by merging `ServiceProxy1` class into `ServiceClient1` by using `ServiceClient1 : IServiceProxyFactory<ServiceClient1>` trick.

```
public interface IServiceProxyFactory<T>
{
    // can have a better name like SetCredentials()
    T GetServiceProxy();
}

// Got rid of ServiceProxy1 class
public partial class ServiceClient1 : IServiceProxyFactory<ServiceClient1>
{
    public ServiceClient1 GetServiceProxy()
    {
        var client = this;
        // set credentials here
        //client.ClientCredentials = "";
        return client;
    }
}

public partial class ServiceClient2 : IServiceProxyFactory<ServiceClient2> { ... } 

public static class ServiceMod<TClient>
    where TClient : class, ICommunicationObject, IServiceProxyFactory<TClient>, new()
{
    public static TReturn Use<TReturn>(Func<TClient, TReturn> codeBlock)
    {
        TClient client = default(TClient);
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            client = new TClient().GetServiceProxy();
            TReturn result = codeBlock(client);
            client.Close();
            success = true;
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now I can do:

```
Service<ServiceClient1>.Use(svc => svc.Method());
```

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, and it's also good to be a self-learner. Besides, I actually found in the first place it should be `Service<ServiceClient1>.Use(svc => svc.Method());` because of the signature of `Action<T>` in original question. So I then think the only possible thing is `ServiceProxy` and `ServiceClient` are the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

- Code

  ```
  partial class TestClass {
      public static void TestMethod() {
          Service<ServiceProxy1>.Use(svc => svc.Method());
          Service<ServiceProxy1>.Use(svc => svc.Method());
          Service<ServiceProxy1>.Use(svc => svc.Method());
          Service<ServiceProxy2>.Use(svc => svc.Method());
      }
  }

  public partial interface IServiceProxyFactory<T> {
      T GetServiceProxy();
  }

  public partial class Service<T> where T: ServiceProxy, new() {
      public static void Use(Action<T> codeBlock) {
          using(var client=ServiceProxy.GetServiceProxy<T>().GetServiceProxy() as T)
              try {
                  codeBlock(client);
              }
              catch {
                  throw;
              }
      }
  }

  public abstract partial class ServiceProxy: CommunicationObject, IDisposable {
      public static T GetServiceProxy<T>() where T: ServiceProxy, new() {
          var proxy=m_List.FirstOrDefault(x => typeof(T).Equals(x.GetType())) as T;

          if(null==proxy) {
              proxy=new T();
              m_List.Add(proxy);
          }

          return proxy;
      }

      public abstract ServiceProxy GetServiceProxy();
      public abstract void Method();

      protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
          lock(ThisLock)
              if(!this.IsDisposed&&disposing) {
                  this.Close();

                  if(!this.IsDisposed)
                      this.Abort();
              }
      }

      public void Dispose() {
          this.Dispose(true);
          GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
      }

      ~ServiceProxy() {
          this.Dispose(false);
      }

      static List<ServiceProxy> m_List=new List<ServiceProxy>();
  }

  public partial class ServiceProxy1: ServiceProxy {
      protected override IAsyncResult OnBeginClose(
          TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state
          ) {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      protected override IAsyncResult OnBeginOpen(
          TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state
          ) {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      protected override void OnAbort() {
      }

      protected override void OnEndClose(IAsyncResult result) {
      }

      protected override void OnEndOpen(IAsyncResult result) {
      }

      protected override void OnClose(TimeSpan timeout) {
      }

      protected override void OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) {
      }

      protected override TimeSpan DefaultCloseTimeout {
          get {
              return TimeSpan.Zero;
          }
      }

      protected override TimeSpan DefaultOpenTimeout {
          get {
              return TimeSpan.Zero;
          }
      }

      public override ServiceProxy GetServiceProxy() {
          var client=new ServiceProxy1();
          // set credentials here
          return client;
      }

      public override void Method() {
      }
  }

  public partial class ServiceProxy2: ServiceProxy1 {
      public override ServiceProxy GetServiceProxy() {
          var client=new ServiceProxy2();
          // set credentials here
          return client;
      }
  }
  ```

Something to mention:

1. `lock` are safe to be re-entered
2. It's impossible for me to do the exactly same declaration of a *reversed* inference from `T` to a type of any `Generic<T>`, such as from `ServiseClient` to `ServiceProxy<ServiceClient>`.
3. According to 2, `ServiceProxy` and `ServiceClient` are just the same thing in the code, so there's no `ServiceClient`.
4. `ServiceProxy` itself is *abstract*. For the requirement of `ServiceClient` need to be convert to `ICommunicationObject` and according to 3 plus for the convenience reason, `ServiceProxy` derives from `CommunicationObject`; and then for ***Is there a better way than ...*** stuff, it implements `IDisposible`
5. For the static instances of a concrete class which inherits `ServiceProxy`, each would have ***only one*** instance, and stored in `m_List`, and calling the static generic version of `GetServiceProxy<T>()` just get them. This appears it's more like the flyweight pattern.
6. According to 5, the interface `IServiceProxyFactory<T>` is not used at all, just put it there for look and feel happy.
7. The instance version of `GetServiceProxy()` is kept the original usage, but concrete class would need to override it.
8. In the `Use` method, the created client is used with a *using* statement. I've read the [Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx), but seems I'm not aware the strategy you would like to handle the exceptions, thus I just *try* and *rethrow*.
9. According to 1, I'm consider a *thread safe* way by lock to dispose atomically, the inherited `IsDisposed` and `ThisLock` are used. The `Close` and `Abort` are doing there accordingly.
10. Oh ten! The class `ServiceProxy2` and `ServiceProxy1` are just for sample, and `ServiceProxy2` derives from `ServiceProxy1`.

The code looks verbose but in fact very simple design. Just report me for the issues and I'll try to correct it. Wish helps anda GOOD **LOCK**!

Comment: just FYI: for the 8th point: the Dispose should never throw and even more, you should be able to safely call Dispose many times on an already-disposed object. There's no such problem as "exception hiding with Using" - the problem is in invalid implementation of one's Dispose method

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Oh, sure. I mainly assumed that I don't know if any possible thrown, even before dispose. So leave a *try and rethrow* should be applicable way. And thank you very much!

Comment: @KenKin, I ended up going with my answer below. But your use of `partial` nudged me in the right direction and so I'm going to give you the bounty.