# Generic inference of type parameter with constraint to other type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Given these classes:

```
public abstract class HostBase
{}
public abstract class ConfigBase
{}
public abstract class HostBase<TConfig> : HostBase where TConfig : ConfigBase
{
    protected internal TConfig Config { get; set; }
}
public class GenericHost : HostBase<Config>
{}
public class HostFactory
{
    public static THost Create<THost, TConfig>(TConfig config)
        where THost : HostBase<TConfig>, new()
        where TConfig : ConfigBase
    {
        return new THost { Config = config };
    } 
}
```

Why can't the compiler infer the type of `TConfig` from `HostFactory.Create<GenericHost>(new Config())`? It seems to me that there is only one possible type for `TConfig`?

I don't get an inference error from the compiler, though:

> The type '`GenericHost`' must be convertible to `HostBase<TConfig>` in order to use it as parameter '`THost`' in the generic method '`THost HostFactory.Create<THost, TConfig>(TConfig)`'

This error seems strange, because this does compile: `HostBase<Config> h = new GenericHost()`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't infer just *some* type parameters within a method call. Generic type inference either infers *all* type parameters, or none. There's no way of inferring `THost` from the parameters (there could be multiple classes which derive from `HostBase<Config>`), which means you basically can't use type inference for that method.

Looking at this specific example, I think you're going to find it tricky to use type inference at all, because of the way the relationships work.

Comment: Ah, didn't remember that limitation. And yes, I thought about moving the `THost` parameter to the class, but since I need to constrain it on `TConfig` that doesn't work... The reason for this is that there are other implementations of the non-generic `HostBase`, my goal was to have the same syntax for all instantiations regardless of type. But I guess that isn't possible without changing some of the foundations then

Comment: @carlpett: A similar question answered(also by Mr. Skeet) in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619038/is-there-a-syntax-does-a-reversed-type-inference