# Disposing/Cleaning up web service proxies

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice-client

What is the best practise for Disposing/Cleaning up a web service proxy instance after synchronous usage?

How does the answer differ if the proxy class is derived from `SoapHttpClientProtocol` versus `ClientBase<T>`?

**Background**

I'm trying to figure out why one of my WCF web services sometimes seems to get into a state where it no longer reponds to service calls. Basically it seems like it hangs and for now I don't really have any hard data to figure out what's going on when this occurrs.

One thing that I suspect might be an issue is the fact that this WCF service is itself doing web service calls to a few other services. These other services are called (synchronously) using proxies that are derived from `SoapHttpClientProtocol` (made using wsdl.exe) and at this time these proxy instances are left to be cleaned up by the finalizer:

```
...
var testProxy = new TestServiceProxy();
var repsonse = testProxy.CallTest("foo");

// process the reponse
...
```

So should I simply wrap these up in a `using(...) { ... }` block?

```
...
using(var testProxy = new TestServiceProxy())
{
    var repsonse = testProxy.CallTest("foo");

    // process the reponse
}
...
```

What if I were to change these proxy classes to be based on `ClientBase<T>` by recreating them using `svcutil.exe`? Based on my research so far, it seems the `Dipose()` method of classes derived from `ClientBase<T>` will internally call the `Close()` method of the class and this method might in turn throw exceptions. So wrapping a proxy based on `ClientBase<T>` in a `Using()` is not always safe.

So to reiterate the question(s):

- How should I clean up my web service proxy after using it when the proxy is based on `SoapHttpClientProtocol`?
- How should I clean up my web service proxy after using it when the proxy is based on `ClientBase<T>`?

Answer (score 14):

Based on my best efforts to find the answer to this question, I'd say that for `SoapHttpClientProtocol` based proxies (regular **.asmx** web service proxies) the correct way is to simly wrap it in `using()`:

```
using(var testProxy = new TestAsmxServiceProxy())
{
    var response = testProxy.CallTest("foo");

    // process the reponse
}
```

For proxies based on `ClientBase<T>` (**WCF** proxies) the answer is that it should not be wrapped in a `using()` statement. Instead the following pattern should be used ([msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx)):

```
var client = new TestWcfServiceProxy();
try
{
    var response = client.CallTest("foo");
    client.Close();

    // process the response
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
    throw;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the first part of this. `Dispose` is implemented by `Component`, but `Abort` is implemented by `WebClientProtocol`. Looking at the code it appears that `Dispose` couldn't know about the request. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647786.aspx seems to back that up (under "Abort Connections for ASP.NET Pages That Timeout Before a Web Services Call Completes").

For WCF, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue