# Close .asmx Web Service proxy class instance

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, proxy, asmx

I have few questions lined up regarding web service,

1. Why should we close web service proxy class instance?
2. how should we close web service proxy class instance for asmx web services?
3. As using statement itself call dispose method at end, What if close function throws exception from dispose method? - So using statement should be used with try catch for traditional asmx web service for better code clean up ?

Thankful if anybody got a chance to stop by and answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disposing/Cleaning up web service proxies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355941/disposing-cleaning-up-web-service-proxies)

Comment: no its not duplicate its something more deep than other one. It's only talking about the asmx service only not WCf service as it expose close and abort functions to clean up stuff.