# Unit testing a object that has dependency on wcf service

Tags: .net, wcf, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I am trying to code an class that has a dependency on a WCF Service, and I would like my class to be unit testable. I came up with the below code, but got into a bit of tricky situation

```
public class BenefitReason
{
    private IWCFServiceClient _client;

    public  BenefitReason(IWCFServiceClient client)
    {
       _client = client;
    }

    public CanIssueEmercengyBenefit(string benefitReasonCode)
    {
         client.GetEmergencyBenefits().contains(benefitReasonCode);
    }
    //Rest of implementation for Benefit Reason
}
```

This is unit testable as I can mock `IWCFServiceClient`, however I lost the control over my client. If the client channel closed between the times the `BenefitReason` object is created and `CanIssueEmercengyBenefit` is called then an exception occurs.

Please advice on how to get past this tricky situation of writing code that can be unit-tested vs losing the control on wcf client instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An addition to TrueWill's answer, you can build a proxy for this:

```
public WCFServiceClientProxy : IWCFServiceClient
{
    public Benefit[] GetEmergencyBenefits()
    {
        using (var client = new WCFServiceClient())
        {
            return client.GetEmergencyBenefits();
        }
    }
}
```

By injecting the `WCFServiceClientProxy` on each call, you prevent any failures and allow to keep the client unaware of the WCF service.

And while you're at it, prevent calling that interface `IWCFServiceClient`, since it shouldn't concern the client whether it is calling a WCF service or a database.

Comment: +1 with two suggestions: (1) dispose of the WCF client in a different manner (see the link in my answer) and (2) return something other than an array from the proxy (arrays are an implementation detail).

Comment: @TrueWill: About point (1). Thanks for the reference. I was unaware of that. I don't agree with your second point though. An List<T> is an implementation detail, an array is just a primitive structure and this communicates that the class will not hold on to the collection (compared to returning `Collection<T>` which implies keeping a reference). And besides, it was just an example :-).

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking more of `IEnumerable<Benefit>`. That way if the OP later changes the implementation to a database or whatever, the result does not have to be converted to an array. As for the `using` issue, too few people are aware of this. It's an egregious case of Microsoft ignoring their own standards.

Comment: @TrueWill I read the MSDN article with horror. The WCF team failed to follow the Framework Design Guidelines and this behavior is really bad. They screwed up.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to instantiate and dispose of the WCF service client in every method call of the interface implementation.

See [What is the best workaround for the WCF client `using` block issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue) for handling disposal properly.