# Is it imperative to explicitly close the client?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcfserviceclient

I've seen a pre-existing code that uses automatically generated client for accessing a WCF. The original version, as suggested on the auto-generated page is as follows.

```
public int GetNumber()
{
  ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
  int number = client.GetNumber();
  client.Close();
  return number;
}
```

It's been refactored to the following.

```
public int GetNumber()
{
  ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
  return number.GetNumber();
}
```

I'm not sure if it's guaranteed that the client will be closed (be that by GC or any other thingy). Is it or should I suggest adding the two lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are correct in that the `.Close()` can be omitted.
As long as there are incomplete asynchronous tasks, the client will not be disposed, not by calling `.Close()` and not by the client object going out of scope. A `using` statement for WCF services appears to be ill-advised, as the (great) link from John in the comments below indicates.

Comment: Actually, this is one of the very few places to _not_ use a `using` block. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue?rq=1.

Comment: very interesting to know, thanks John. I stand corrected and will edit my answer

Comment: Hmm... Who put +1 on the reply below advocating usage of *using* and defending the application of *Close()*? Based on the information, I'd like to see **this** reply as more +ified but I've by principle avoided downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke `Close` method. Or use following code snippet which despose `client` object on exit out of `using` block

```
using(ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient())
{
    return number.GetNumber();
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is one of the very few places to _not_ use a `using` block. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue?rq=1.