# Best practice to call WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have always learned that **never** use *using* statement when calling WCF Service like this

```
using (Service.YourClientProxy client = new Service.YourClientProxy())
{
    var time = client.Time();
}
```

So I am always using this to call Service

```
YourClientProxy clientProxy = new YourClientProxy();

try
{
   .. use your service
   clientProxy.Close();
}
catch(FaultException)
{
   clientProxy.Abort();
}
catch(CommunicationException)
{
   clientProxy.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{ 
   clientProxy.Abort();
}
```

I have been reading och stackoverflow and I have read this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue)
Service.cs class taken from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue)

**I would like to know if this below is a good practice to call WCF service and does this really close the service?**

```
public static class Service<TChannel>
{
    public static ChannelFactory<TChannel> ChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<TChannel>("*");

    public static TReturn Use<TReturn>(Func<TChannel, TReturn> codeBlock)
    {
        var proxy = (IClientChannel)ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        var success = false;
        try
        {
            var result = codeBlock((TChannel)proxy);
            proxy.Close();
            success = true;
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                proxy.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Invoking service from client like this.

```
        var time = Service<Service.YourServiceChannel>.Use(resultAsync =>
        {
            return resultAsync.TimeAsync();
        });
```

Comment: I made a reference and read that post and it wasn't clear to me what was the best practice. I was also asking if that code sample that I was referring really closed the connection.

Answer (score 4):

From this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056(v=vs.110).aspx

It seems the best practice is to call Dispose is by calling Close in a try block:

```
try
{
    client.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
    client.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    client.Abort();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    client.Abort();
    throw;
}
```

You can also add logging or whatever else in each `catch` block.

Comment: -1: where's your `Dispose`? And this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Isn't calling Close() the same thing as calling Dispose() here?

Comment: Pretty much, in which case your answer should say "`Close`" and not "`Dispose`".