# Windows Server can not use WCF Server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I can use this program on my own computer, but I can not use on the server.

Server use supreme authority Administrator to open the program.

Server WCF HTTP Activation Feature with .NET4.5 is opening.

Server endpoint address use "http://localhost" like following

> endpoint address="http://localhost" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" name="ProductService" contract="ProductService.IWCFProductService"

Wrong Message:

> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
>
> Stack trace at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
>
> at FileUtilityHelperService.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: You're not seeing the root cause exception, because you most likely (need code to be sure) run in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/573872/21567) issue. Workaround as described in the link and post the actual exception details.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that there has been an unexpected exception somewhere in your code. The error message "*...because it is in the Faulted state*" means that communication between the server and the client is unusable. 
What you need is better error handeling.

1. Use `try/catch` around your code that can potentially generate an exception
2. Always order exeptions from the most specific to the least specific

You would probably like to log your errors to a file or database, [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is great for this (and comes as a nuget package)