# WCF Client Proxy usage, String information held in memory by Timer. Leak?

Tags: c#, wcf, timer, proxy

I'm working with a WCF Client which looks like it's leaving String connection information in memory after an explicit close & the proxy going out of scope. The implementation I'm using is similar to this post:

[Link to another stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue/)

I do the close on the Channel have confirmed it's not usable a second time. If I use DotMemory to analyze the memory I see 8 strings kept which look relative to the REST call mechanics.  Retention objects look like this:

```
System.Net.TimerThread+TimerQueue ->
System.Net.TimerThread+TimerNode ->
System.Net.ConnectionGroup ->
System.Collections.ArrayList ->
System.Object[] ->
System.Net.Connection ->
System.Net.CoreResponseData ->
System.Net.WebHeaderCollection ->
System.String[] ->
System.String
```

The client I'm using to test this does almost nothing. A button which creates the proxy, uses it and then closes, my REST call works no problem.

using DotMemory Retention Path I see 2 paths which run through Timer:

```
System.Net.TimerThread+TimerQueue : Roots={Handle, Static reference }.m_Timers ->
System.Net.TimerThread+TimerNode.next ->
System.Net.TimerThread+TimerNode
```

Retention path of System.Net.TimerThread+Callback

```
System.Net.TimerThread+TimerQueue : Roots={Handle, Static reference }.m_Timers ->
System.Net.TimerThread+TimerNode.prev ->
System.Net.TimerThread+TimerNode.m_Callback ->
System.Net.TimerThread+Callback
```

If I want to figure out why the timer is in play, my guess is something weird is going on with the WebChannelFactory, maybe a default property I'm unaware of. This is just a straight REST call without any callback abilities.

Thanks for your patience, I'm a self taught C# person so please be gentle!

Comment: What's the problem in keeping the strings in memory? Did you force a garbage collection?

Comment: I used GC.Collect(). I realize it might not be a leak but just bad memory usage on my applications part,  but if I .Close and allow the proxy to go out of scope, it can't do useful work again so I don't want it to consume resources however little.  Having the static Timer reference holding that string information just perplexed me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your retention path it looks like you're hitting the internal timer for closing service points.

This is controlled by `System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime` property and default value is 100 seconds.

So, you can either try to see if these strings disappear after you keep your application idle for 2 minutes or just set this timeout to something small (like 1 second) before calling your WCF client.

Comment: Terrific! I'll check this out and post my results. Thank you for your input!

Comment: This is looking good! If I reset the value to 5 seconds, wait and GC DotMemory doesn't show those timer references at the time of retained memory.. Excellent! Thank you Mr. Labutin!

Comment: Good. Then the original problem is not a leak as such. These strings will be collected eventually. It'll just take almost 2 minutes.