# How to get a WCF ClientBase<T> in a faulted state?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, faultexception

As I remember correctly, in .NET Framework 3.x, a WCF service client (`ClientBase<T>`) would get a faulted state when the service returned an exception (`FaultException`). This could result in problems when the service client was not disposed / closed correctly. (See the many posts about this subject, like: [What is the best workaround for the WCF client `using` block issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue)).

This behavior has been changed! Somehow, when the service throws an exception, the service client rethrows that exception, but the client does not enter a faulted state anymore.

Two questions:

1. Under which conditions does the service client enter a faulted state?
2. Since when (what framework version or patch) has this behavior been altered?

Comment: Unplug the network cable?

Comment: @MickyD: I did not try that. I did try to turn off a service before opening a channel or halfway communication.

Comment: I could not find documentation about `ServiceClient<T>`.  Is `ServiceClient<T>` similar to `IClientChannel`?  With a `ChannelFactory<T>` and `CreateChannel()` I can get the client into `Faulted` state by connecting to an unexisting EndPoint, but that appears not to work for the OP.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; I used the wrong class name. I changed it to `ClientBase<T>`.