# How do I dispose of a connected service in .net core 2.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

When adding a connected service in .net core 2.0 using the **WCF Web Service Reference provider** to a SOAP interface the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase version 4.2.0.0 no longer has the IDisposable interface found in version 4.0.0.0.

This means I can no longer wrap it in a using statement (or use try/finally and dispose of the object) like so:

```
using (MyClass.MyClassSoapClient client = new MyClass.MyClassSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration.MyClassSoap))
```

I can't figure out why IDisposable was removed and whether I should attempt to implement it myself, or if the intention is for me to use the SOAP interface in a different manner in .net core?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: I found out what to do. You should use wcf differently now in .net core http://tattoocoder.com/asp-net-core-getting-clean-with-soap/

Comment: I ended up using a try/catch/finally insteading of "using" and calling "Close" in finally on the client:

MyClass.MyClassSoapClient client = new MyClass.MyClassSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration.MyClassSoap);
try
{
 // use client
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 logger.Error("MyClassSoapClient exception" + e.Message);
}
finally
{
 ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
}

Comment: You should actually never have wrapped it in a using because it could throw exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue

Comment: Indeed, I feel like using is a bit of a trap.