# wcf file upload netnamedpipe pipe closed error

Tags: file-upload, wcf, wcf-binding, netnamedpipebinding

I am uploading a file in asp.net..via file upload control. I am taking the stream from posted file and convert to byte array and pass to service.
 I am getting this error:here was an error writing to the pipe: The pipe is being closed. (232, 0xe8).

We r using netNamedPipe binding..hosted in windows service..This error is for uploading over 6KB..No issue in downloading..I have increased the timeout and max message size values to large ones..but still error is there..

Comment: Please post your code where the exception occurs, and the full exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was increasing the ReceiveTimeout of the netNamedPipe Binding, since it controls the channel idle timeout. Something like that:

```
<netNamedPipeBinding>
<binding name="myBinding" receiveTimeout="infinite">
</binding>
```

See also this question: [How can I make Named Pipe binding reconnect automatically in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340521/how-can-i-make-named-pipe-binding-reconnect-automatically-in-wcf)